# Visual Programming tools that can be used for practical app development

Tags: visual-programming

I've been interested in [Visual Programming Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language) (VPL) for a while. However I've hardly seen any environments that can be used for practical projects such as Windows apps or web services.

I've heard of the following:

- [LabVIEW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LabVIEW) - electronics and instrumentation
- [Microsoft VPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Programming_Language) - robotics
- [Game Maker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Maker) - games
- [Google App Inventor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Inventor) - Android apps
- [Tersus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tersus) - web apps

Are there any other VPL environments that generate **executable programs** and can be used for practical applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it is practical enough for you but you can have a look at Thyrd, which was recently featured in the last Emerging Languages conference:

http://thyrd.org/

It is not just yet another visual stuff, there is really something there

Answer (score 2):

Probably a bit too late for this answer, but I'm interested in the same thing and for anyone else might read this and find it useful.
Here is a new one just for creating windows applications, it's called [Korduene](http://www.korduene.com/), however beware it is alpha just now.

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look at the WPF based [TUM.CMS.VPLControl](https://github.com/tumcms/TUM.CMS.VPLControl)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Yahoo Pipes](http://pipes.yahoo.com/) has a somehow limited scope, but I suppose it is one of the more popular examples of visual programming tools that are really used in practice.

Answer (score 1):

DRAKON Editor
http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/
It generates code for compilation or interpretetion, not actual executable.
It it supports visual programming in several programming languages, including Java, Processing.org, D, C#, C/C++ (with Qt support), Python, Tcl, Javascript, Lua and Erlang.
Why to use DRAKON than other diagramming systems?

- No line intersections. You will never find in DRAKON diagram two or
  more lines intersecting each other! Not seen in other diagramming
  systems!
- Silhouette structure. It allows to break one diagram in to several
  logical parts. Not seen in other diagramming systems!
- No slanting or curved lines. Only straight lines with right angles.
- Icons are placed only on vertical lines.
- Branching is done in a simple, visible and consistent way.
- Each diagram has one entry and one exit.

More about DRAKON here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DRAKON

Answer (score 0):

i recomend Outsystems for .net/java , it´s a great app [Outsystems](http://www.outsystems.com/)